# knockout custom elements - with nested html

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to achieve the following. I know I can do it via the params object but it is not too easy on the eye.

```
<custom-element>
    <span>Hello</span>
   </custom-element>

ko.components.register('custom-element', {
viewModel: {
    createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo, NESTED_CONTENT) {
      //do something with span element;
    }
```

In the createViewModel function you are passed a componentInfo object that has an element property.
It would be nice if I could get the nested content too.
Is there somewhere for me to hook into to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible in knockout version `3.2`, however it would be possible in the next version, after this [commit](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/commit/58dec530bdc27942c80f531700e611edfb9706fd) this, feel free to look at the [tests](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/348f9eab6cab5e253d1d663c7b9ed1dcb692206d/spec/components/componentBindingBehaviors.js#L174).

Now there is only way to pass parameters to component only via `params` property. But in the next version you would be probably able to use `$componentTemplateNodes` in your template like:

```
ko.components.register('custom-element', {
template:
    '<div data-bind="template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes }" />'
}
```

P.S. it's already a part of the [3.3.0-alpha](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/tag/v3.3.0-alpha) release.

Comment: perfect. I'll take a look.

Comment: Took a look, just what I wanted.